# How to plot against time on x-axis Highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Here is my fiddle : [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ms91r4pr/7/)

Click on add to array button to add objects to the data array.
The payload object has time, temperature and humidity.

```
$("#addToArray").click(function() {
  if(myChartTemperature) {
    myChartTemperature.series[0].addPoint(payload.temperature);
  }
  if(myChartHumidity){
    myChartHumidity.series[0].addPoint(payload.humidity);
  }
 dataArray.push((payload));
  console.log(dataArray);
})
```

How can I plot temperature/humidity against time on the x-axis (assuming time data will be sent through an api call to the sensor data and will change)?

Answer (score 2):

By setting [`xAxis.type`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type) to `datetime`, and [`series.line.data.x`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data.x) to the timestamp of the event in *milliseconds* you can achieve what you are asking.

That is:

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  ...
}
```

And

```
$("#addToArray").click(function() {
  if(myChartTemperature) {
    myChartTemperature.series[0].addPoint({
       x: new Date().getTime(), 
       y: payload.temperature
    });
  }
  if(myChartHumidity){
    myChartHumidity.series[0].addPoint({
      x: new Date().getTime(), 
      y: payload.humidity
    });
  }
  dataArray.push((payload));
  console.log(dataArray);
})
```

**Working example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/ms91r4pr/6/

(note that I only did this for the points added after 5 seconds, so you need to adjust the function that adds before 5 seconds as well)

Comment: The time data vary in seconds and the change/graph is not evidently visible. How do I fix this? Data sample : [{"time":"2018:02:06 16:19:23","temperature":"25.0","humidity":"14.0"},{"time":"2018:02:06 16:19:26","temperature":"25.0","humidity":"14.0"},{"time":"2018:02:06 16:19:28","temperature":"25.0","humidity":"14.0"},{"time":"2018:02:06 16:19:31","temperature":"25.0","humidity":"13.0"},{"time":"2018:02:06 16:19:33","temperature":"25.0","humidity":"14.0"},{"time":"2018:02:06 16:19:36","temperature":"25.0","humidity":"14.0"}

Comment: @webendthetrend I don't understand what that means. That said, you need to input time in milliseconds. Not as a string.

Comment: So you would like to achieve something similar to this example? http://jsfiddle.net/x1cxp9tu/